# Camunda recover process from end state

Tags: camunda

given the following PoC of Camunda process defined as it follows in Camunda Modeler:

[image]

Is there a way to recover the process instance execution from status EXPIRED to IDLE? And if positive, how exactly?

More info:

1. TIMEOUT is a TIMER BOUNDARY EVENT that after N days makes the process evolve in state EXPIRED.
2. EXPIRED is a TERMINATE END EVENT.
3. IDLE is an USER TASK

Maybe a combination of both https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/process-definition/post-restart-process-instance-sync/ and https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/process-instance/post-modification-async/ fits my case but I'm not certain.

This is a PoC, in real life scenario we could have lot of intermediate steps with lot of input data coming from customers, including file uploads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the restart method would allow you to do this. Use the instructions to set the new target state.The documentation includes and example at the bottom:

```
{
  "instructions": [
    {
      "type": "startAfterActivity",
      "activityId": "aUserTask"
    }
  ],
  "initialVariables" : true,
  "skipCustomListeners" : true,
  "withoutBusinessKey" : true,
  "historicProcessInstanceQuery": {
    "processDefinitionId": "aProcessDefinitionId",
    "processInstanceBusinessKey" : "businessKey"
  }
}
```

In your scenario you don't need to use terminating end event. It is better to use normal end events whenever you can (and make sure the token flow is well understood and tested).

An possibly cleaner alternative to terminating the process instance would be to use a wait state like a message receive event and continue the processes in a clearly visible modeled manner when this business scenario occurs.